# jQuery toggle switch not changing values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a CSS3 toggle that i've tied into my AJAX script to simply change 1 of 2 values in a database column (and vice-versa on toggle again). I cant seem to get both values 'pagination' and 'infinite' sent to the database.

I really didn't know what was going on, as my script is fine. So i used RequestBin endpoint to see what was happening, and **I'm getting only 1 value sent in POST request to my endpoint at all times**, while toggling on/off just sends the same value 'pagination' over to requestbin which makes no sense. I've utilized **prop()** for this, which to me is much like my light use of the ternary op in PHP.

My JS code:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.switch').click(function() {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "https://-------.x.pipedream.net", // temporary endpoint for testing
             data: {
                  value: $(this).toggleClass("switchOn") ? 'pagination' : 'infinite'
                  //value: $(this).prop("checked") ? 'pagination' : 'infinite'
             },
             success: function(data) {
                 //$('#foo1').html(data);
             }
         });
     });
   });
```

And my markup

```
<div class="wrapper-toggle" align="center">
   <label>
      <div class="switch"></div>
      <div class="switch-label">Use <b>Paged</b> results instead (Current: <b>Infinite</b>)</div>
   </label>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.wrapper-toggle{  
   width:500px;  
   margin:0 auto;  
   }  
   .switch{  
   display:inline;
   float:left;
   width:200px;  
   height:100px;  
   background:#E5E5E5;  
   z-index:0;  
   margin:0;  
   padding:0;  
   appearance:none;  
   border:none;  
   cursor:pointer;  
   position:relative;  
   border-radius:100px;  
   }  
   .switch:before{  
   content: ' ';  
   position:absolute;  
   left:5px;  
   top:5px;  
   width:190px;  
   height:90px;  
   background:#FFFFFF;  
   z-index:1;  
   border-radius:95px;  
   }  
   .switch:after{  
   content:' ';  
   width:88px;  
   height:88px;  
   border-radius:86px;  
   z-index:2;  
   background:#FFFFFF;  
   position:absolute;  
   transition-duration:500ms;  
   top:6px;  
   left:6px;  
   box-shadow:0 2px 5px #999999;  
   }  
   .switchOn, .switchOn:before{  
   background:#E92324; !important;  
   }  
   .switchOn:after{  
   left:105px;   
   } 
   .switch-label {
   display:inline;
   float:left;
   text-align:left;
   padding-top:40px;
   padding-left:10px;
   }
```

I followed the docs on prop() and used a few variations in this regard, and managed to get either one or the other by modifying the code, but no literal toggle => value1 => toggle => value2 => toggle => value1 etc etc. What is going on?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: `toggleClass` toggle between class , to check the class use `hasClass` ... `$(this).hasClass("switchOn") ? 'pagination' : 'infinite'` .. Also I don't prefer to use `$(this)` in ajax even its working .. I prefer to define `var $this = $(this)` on the top and use `$this` in ajax instead

Comment: Same result. This disabled the toggle but provided only 1 value in POST request both ways.

Comment: So you need to use `$(this).toggleClass("switchOn");` before the ajax then use my code above

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much. I learned something here and will be applying this practice to my AJAX logic for now on. I would buy you a beer. Cheers!

Comment: glad to help .. Have a great day :-)